# inheritance and polymorphism c++

Tags: c++

I read up on inheritance and polymorphism but I still can't distinguish what's the difference between both of them.

From what I knew, inheritance is e.g(a derived class inheritance methods from base class and method overriding can be performed as well.) so then what is polymorphism? are both inheritance and polymorphism somehow have the meaning?

Please correct me as I know that I am wrong. Thanks

Comment: Without inheritance, there would be no polymorphic behavior. To better understand polymorphism, try to read this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9260064/1168156 :)

Comment: Some people believe there is only *run-time* polymorphism (with inheritance). Some other people think there is also *compile-time* polymorphism (with templates). You have a privilege to make a choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, we have inheritance but no polymorphism:

```
struct SimpleBase {
  int i;
  int get() const { return i; }
};

struct SimpleDerived: public SimpleBase {
  int get() const { return i + 7; }
};
```

an instance of SimpleBase (or a reference or pointer to it) is always exactly that, and the derived class can't change its behaviour. For example:

```
int foo(SimpleBase const &obj) { return obj.get(); }
```

will always call `SimpleBase::get`, even if I pass in an instance of the derived type.

---

Conversely, with polymorphism, a derived class can override base class methods with its own versions:

```
struct PolyBase {
  int i;
  virtual int get() const { return i; }
};

struct PolyDerived {
  int get() const { return i + 7; }
};

int foo(PolyBase const &obj) { return obj.get(); }
```

Now foo calls a different method depending on the derived type passed in, without *knowing* which derived type it is.

So with polymorphism, a whole family of types can share a common interface, and you can write code once that operates on the interface, without having to know about all the different derived types.

---

The form of polymorphism shown above is *run-time* polymorphism: it generates code that figures out which implementation of each virtual function to call when it runs.

There is also *compile-type* polymorphism, which doesn't require inheritance at all, and instead uses templates.

Say you want to write a sorted container (like std::map) - you don't want to limit it to storing a particular data type, but you do need some way to compare two elements to see which is bigger.

The run-time approach might provide an abstract base class, like

```
struct LessThanComparable {
  virtual bool operator< (LessThanComparable const &) const = 0;
};
```

and require every type you want to put in your container, to derive from this and implement `operator<`. Then, you can write `if (a < b)` in your container code, and the right function  for the type you're storing will be called (*).

```
// requires inheritance from abstract base class,
// uses virtual call to operator<
bool less_than(LessThanComparable const &a, LessThanComparable const &b) {
    return a < b;
}
```

The compile-type approach actually used (**) in the STL is to state that every stored type must model the *LessThanComparable* concept, by providing a suitable `operator<`. However, this is resolved at compile time, and no common base class is required.

```
// doesn't require any inheritance, doesn't use virtual function call,
template <typename T>
bool less_than(T const &a, T const &b) { return a < b; }
```

---

(*) note also that implementing `operator<` isn't trivial, because `a < b` can be called when *a* and *b* have different derived types. In the template version, we know they both have the same type *T*.

(**) ok, so the default `std::less` has the LessThanComparable requirement, or you can provide an alternative StrictWeakOrdering.

Comment: thank alot for explainations

Answer (score 1):

Polymorphism allows you to morph the class back and forth between its inherited parent classes.  The following is legal, if Dog and Cat class inherits from Animal

```
void takes_animal(Animal &animal) { }

Dog dog;
Cat cat;
takes_animal(dog);
takes_animal(cat);
```

Comment: @VladLazarenko I can see no slicing here (no copy made). Perhaps your commend referred to an earlier version of the answer? If so, it served its purpose, but is confusing now: please remove it.

Comment: The pass by reference was added by Mark Ingram, I didn't want to spell out all the syntax of creating new pointers and deleting etc. and so slicing was neglected.  It's fine now though as you said.

Comment: thank alot for explainations

Answer (score 1):

In farmer`s words, polymorphism is when you work with "base" class (called an interface in some cases) without knowing what the actual implementation really is. Inheritance can be used with or without polymorphism (i.e. when you use inheritance but always know what specific class of object you are dealing with, even if it is inherited from something else, is not a polymorphism). But polymorphism cannot be used without inheritance (it just stops making any sense).

Comment: thank alot for explainations

Answer (score 1):

Inheritance is an implementation technique.  Polymorphism is an
aspect of one of the things you can implement with it.  (It's
not the only thing.  For example, inheriting from
`std::iterator` has nothing to do with polymorphism.)

Answer (score 0):

Your are right about inheritance but it is not that simple. Overloading and Overriding are also important functions of inheritance. While, polymorphism is about creating polymorphic arrays like if parent class is fruits and apples are objects then you can define objects as type of fruits and call general function. Also creating pure virtual function will prevent parent class to make it's instances.

Comment: thank alot for explainations