# Basic polymorphic pointers to base classes

Tags: c++, polymorphism

While I've been working in c++ for a while, I haven't had need to use polymorphic features until now, and I'm very intrigued by them.

If I have a base class `ClassA` and another `ClassB` derives from it, I understand that I can have `virtual` member function in `ClassA` that, when implemented in `ClassB`, will be called in a `ClassB` instance even if that instance is pointed at using a `ClassA` pointer. Without this `virtual` keyword, I presume the base class implementation would prevail when using a base class pointer, yet be operating on an object that was instantiated from the subclass, which seems questionable to me if in fact `ClassB` has its own implementation of the same function that is effectively ignored in such a case.

Is this a correct understanding of polymorphic behavior?

Now the real question is how do you refer to `ClassB` using a pointer to is base class. I can really only think of two ways:

1. Create the pointer at the time of instantiation, using a function that returns a base class pointer while actually allocating memory for the subclass instead, using the subclass's constructor. (Does such a creation function have a common name?)
2. Casting an object using `static_cast` and assigning it to a pointer to the base class.

Are these the two main techniques for generating base class pointers to objects of a subclass?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5854581/46821

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The easiest way is to simply assign it, no cast necessary:

```
ClassA *ptrA = new ClassB;
```

You're correct that you need the `virtual` keyword to enable polymorphic behavior.  Here's one way to think about it.  C++ operates on the static type of an object.  When you call `ptrA->foo()`, the type of the pointer is `ClassA*`.  If that function is not declared `virtual`, then it will blindly call `ClassA`'s version of the function.  There's no other choice.  But if `foo()` is `virtual`, then it knows to stop and ask, "Wait, what type am I really?"  And the answer in that case is `ClassB`, so it will call `ClassB`'s version.

Also note that you don't need pointers to achieve this.  Another common way you'll see polymorphism in action is via a function call:

```
void bar(ClassA &aObj)
{
    aObj.foo();
}

// ...
ClassB bObj;
bar(bObj);
```

Comment: indeed, I was just coincidentally looking up a word in the dictionary, the word was *elegant* and I did a double-take when the definition was in fact the exact code snippet you provided above!

Comment: +1 for pointing out that dynamic allocation & pointers are orthogonal to polymorphism (even if often used together).