# Calling a virtual function on a vector of base classes

Tags: c++, virtual

I created some code to reproduce the problem:

```cpp
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class A
{
protected:
    int m_X;
public:
    A() { 
        std::cout << "in A ctor" << std::endl; 
        m_X = 0;
    }
    virtual void printX(){ std::cout << "in A " << m_X << std::endl; }
};

class B : public A
{
public:
    B() {
        std::cout << "in B ctor" << std::endl; 
        m_X = 1;
    }
    virtual void printX(){ std::cout << "in B " << m_X << std::endl; }
};

class As
{
public:
    void AddA( const A &a ){ m_As.push_back( a ); }
    void PrintXs()
    {
        for ( auto a : m_As )
        {
            a.printX();
        }
    }
private:
    std::vector<A> m_As;
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    As as;
    B b;
    as.AddA( b );
    as.PrintXs();
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

The output of this is:

in A ctor

in B ctor

in A 1

I want "in B 1" instead of "in A 1". I'm sure my understanding of virtual is flawed. How must I change the code to call the B PrintX()? Note that there will be other classes that inherit from A so I really don't want to code a static call.

Thanks.

Comment: Polymorphism requires pointers or references!  At `m_As.push_back( a );`, the object referenced by `a` is being copy-constructed into a new `A` object.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you're doing is called [slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-the-slicing-problem-in-c).  This is where you take an object of a derived class and trim off everything that is not in the parent and assign it to the parent.

What you want to do is use [polymorphism](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5854581/polymorphism-in-c) to do what you explained.  To do this, change your vector from a copy of the object, to a ptr to the object.

If interested in more details, please use the links provided, the information included in them seems to be very complete.

Answer (score 3):

The quick fix is to change your `As` class to the following:

```
class As
{
public:
    void AddA( A &a ){ m_As.push_back( &a ); }
    void PrintXs()
    {
        for ( auto a : m_As )
        {
            a->printX();
        }
    }
private:
    std::vector<A*> m_As;
};
```

When you use `std::vector<A> m_As;`, the vector can only fit `A` objects. If you use pointers instead then polymorphism can work and call the correct `printX` function. However, this has the problem of dangling pointer if the lifetime of the pointed to object expires. To handle that it would be better to use a smart pointer class like `std::unique_ptr`.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're passing objects by value you can not take advantages of polymorphism. Pass them by (smart) pointers or references.

```
 std::vector<std::shared_ptr<A>> m_As;

 // or 

 std::vector<std::unique_ptr<A>> m_As;

 // or 

 std::vector<A*> m_As; // be careful of bare pointers

 // or (since C++11)

 std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<A>> m_As;
```

### std::reference_wrapper magic!

For the last one, you can use [`std::reference_wrapper`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper) and [`std::ref`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/ref):

```
class As
{
public:
    void AddA(A &a){ m_As.push_back( std::ref(a) ); }
    void PrintXs() const
    {
        for ( auto a : m_As )
        {
            a.get().printX();
        }
    }
private:
    std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<A>> m_As;
};
```

Using last code, you don't have to change `main` code.

*[Live code](http://ideone.com/rkidCg)*

Comment: [`std::vector<A&>` won't compile.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/922360/501250)  (I had an answer that included that and deleted it as pointers are required, and Jesse beat me to the punch on that.)

Comment: @cdhowie: Of course, I updated my answer and wrote a sample with `std::reference_wrapper` which is reference based.

Answer (score 0):

```
for ( const auto & a : m_As )
{
        a.printX();
}
```

it will keep you from expanded copy and provide the B-instance instead of A-instance, appeared as copy.