# Pure virtual method called terminated

Tags: c++, pure-virtual

I'm trying to use virtual methods in C++.

I have an objects hierarchy:

```
class Action {
public:
    Action() { }

    virtual void action() = 0;
}

class CubeAction : public Action {
public:
    CubeAction() { }

    void action() {
        glutSolidCube(1);
    }
};
```

And I have a container for objects of the base class.

```
class ActionContainer {
private:
    std::vector<Action *> actions;

public:
    void add(Action &action) { actions.push_back(&action); }

    void doActions() {
        for (auto a : actions) {
            a->action();
        }
    }
};
```

And when I try to `doActions`:

```
ActionContainter actions();

CubeAction cubeAction();
actions.add(cubeAction);

actions.doActions();
```

I get `pure virtual method called` error.

I used the [Calling a virtual function on a vector of base classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16326657/calling-a-virtual-function-on-a-vector-of-base-classes) solution, but error still happened.

---

**UPD:** sorry, that is my real code: [Github](https://github.com/wlad031/ssu-coursework-2016). Some bug in `Action.h` file, I think.

Comment: Since the code has syntax errors it's not **real code**. Please post a complete but minimal example that readers can try.

Comment: @JeremyThompson: The link is good, thanks; the acronym however is silly and counter-productive. Don't assume that people who post questions here will know it.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92060/add-data-se-style-magic-links-to-comments - I find them helpful

Comment: Once you fix the obvious compilation errors it works as expected. Post your real code! http://ideone.com/Bd6sMF

Comment: Except syntax errors, the code has no problem. Please give us the real failing code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code in github looks like this:

```
try {
    SphereAction sphereAction(1);
    actions.add(sphereAction);

    CubeAction cubeAction(2);
    actions.add(cubeAction);

} catch (InfoException e) {
    cerr << e.what() << endl;
}
```

and afterwards, you call `display()`, which calls `ActionContainer::doActions()`.

In the container, you store a pointer to the argument, but you pass a local variable to `actions.add()`, which will be out of scope and no longer exist when it is used.

Comment: Thank you very much! But why two of unused vector led to such consequences?

Comment: The destructor gets called, making the virtual function pure again. As the objects are on the stack, the memory is still there, even after the lifetime of the objects, until it gets overwritten.