# what are the different ways to achieve polymorphism in c++

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism

I know there are a few different ways to achieve polymorphism in c++.

I know of 3 ways to  do this:

- by using inheritance (through the use of a pointer to a base class)
- by using virtual function
- by using abstract classes

During a technical discussion on the topic I was told I am missing something and was left hanging...hence I asked the question here.

Is there another way in c++ to to this or is something I said wrong?

Comment: those aren't really different ways. in the end, you will use a pointer to a base class...

Comment: note: they were probably interested in static polymorphism.

Comment: you only talked runtime  polymorphism, maybe we can take compile time polymorphism in count, like template and funciton overloading

Comment: Besides inheritance and templates, there's plain function pointers.

Comment: follow this link [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5854581/polymorphism-in-c) may be you get your answer.

Comment: Please Use this [Link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_(computer_science))

Comment: Besides run time polymorphism,you can achieve compile time polymorphism through operator and function overloading.

Comment: @Subhajit I suspect that the answer they were looking for was templates (but operator and function overloading is also a good answer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your three ways are really just one: whether the base class is
abstract is an implementation detail; you need virtual
functions, which can be overridden in a derived class.

Other than that: both function overloading and templates provide
a form of polymorphism as well, although it is resolved at
compile time, and not run time.  For that matter, you can define
a class in a header file, and provide several different
implementations for it, depending on compile time switches;
that's also a form of polymorphism.  (This is often done for
system dependent code.  The polymorphism is resolved as
a function of the system you're compiling for.)

Answer (score 0):

I think your discussion was related to different types of polymorphism.

1. Compile time polymorphism - Ex: Function Overloading, Operator Overloading.
2. Run time polymorphism - Ex: Inheritance + virtual functions + base class pointer.