# Polymorphism and Pointers (C++)

Tags: c++, class, pointers, polymorphism, virtual

Say the class B inherits from class A and class A contains a virtual function

```
virtual public foo() {cout<<"I'm A"<< endl';}
```

while B contains

```
public foo() {cout<<"I'm B" << endl';}
```

Why is it that

```
A* x = new B;
```

will let x use the function foo() where it prints out "I'm B", but

```
A x = B;
```

would give me the other function?

Comment: Which of the two seems strange to you?

Comment: `A x = B;` won't compile. Anyway, read about [object slicing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing)

Comment: That is just the mechanism for runtime polymorphism provided by C++. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5854581/polymorphism-in-c) answer for a detailed explanation.