# How do you downcast from a base object to a child one

Tags: c++, casting

```
struct BaseObject
{};

struct HardMonster : BaseObject
{
    int Berserk(int);

private:
    std::list<BaseObject> MonsterList;
};
```

I have all the monsters defined as a BaseObject, so it's easier to make a list of them. But when I need to convert the BaseObject into a HardMonster so I can use to the Berserk function. I know, I could do it the easy and just make a temp Hardmonster to calculate the damage from Berserk. But I want to do it the right way.

Comment: The right way is to rethink your design. Being forced to downcast is never a good sign.

Comment: You probably want to use [polymorphism](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5854581/polymorphism-in-c) with [virtual functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2391679/why-do-we-need-virtual-methods-in-c)

Comment: You need at least a `virtual ~Base() {}` destructor, use a `list<std::unique_ptr<BaseObject>> MonsterList;` of pointers and `dynamic_cast<HardMonster*>` to down cast.

Comment: Why all the extra access specifiers?

Answer (score 2):

If you use:

```
list<BaseObject> MonsterList; //This is where the Object list is defined.
```

you will be storing only `BaseObject`s. If you add any object of derived type to the list, you will lose the derived type part in the stored object.

Further reading: [What is object slicing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing)

What you need to store is pointers, preferably smart pointers, to `BaseObject`s.

```
std::list<std::shared_ptr<BaseObject>> MonsterList;
```

From a `std::shared_ptr<BaseObject>`, you can get a `std::shared_ptr<HardMonster>` by using [`dynamic_pointer_cast`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/pointer_cast).

```
std::shared_ptr<BaseObject> baseObject;
std::shared_ptr<HardMonster> monster = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<HardMonster>(baseObject);
if ( monster )
{
    // The cast is successful...
    // Use monster
}
```