# Calling sub-class method from a base-class pointer?

Tags: c++, polymorphism, overriding

I didn't know what to give as a title, I expect more experienced stackoverflow.com users to improve it.

Let's say we have the class A

```
class A {
  void hello(){  cout << "i'm an A" << endl; }
}
```

and its sub-class B

```
class B: public A {
  void hello(){  cout << "i'm a B" << endl; }
}
```

Then we did somewhere in our program

```
A* array[2];
array[0] = new A;
array[1] = new B;
array[0]->hello(); // output: "i'm an A"
array[1]->hello(); // output: "i'm a B"
```

why doesn't the `array[1].hello();` output `I'm a B` since we instanciated a `B` object for that base-class pointer  ? and how to make it happen ?

Comment: Because you didn't declare it virtual.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5854581/polymorphism-in-c

Comment: [No virtual, no override.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/virtual) C++ defaults to the smallest, tightest possible interpretation. If you want fancy tricks, you have to tell it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couple of changes here:

make function hello in class A, a `virtual` and `public:` because by default it is `private`

```
class A {
public: 
virtual void hello(){ cout << "i'm an A" << endl; }
};
```

Similarly make hello in class `B` `virtual`

```
class B: public A {
virtual void hello(){  cout << "i'm a B" << endl; }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to make `hello` a virtual function:

```
class A {
    virtual void hello() { cout << "i'm an A" << endl; }
};

class B : public A {
    virtual void hello() override { cout << "i'm a B" << endl; } // 1) 
};
```

This tells the compiler that the actual function should not be determined by the static type (the type of the pointer or reference) but by the dynamic (run-time) type of the object.

1) The `override`keyword tells the compiler to check, if the function actually overrides a `hello` function in the base class (helps e.g. to catch spelling mistakes or differences in the parameter types).

Comment: I see, I was mistaken, I always thought that `virtual` is C++'s keyword for `abstract` methods. Now I got the right picture of it

Comment: @reaffer: You were partially correct: Abstract methods only make sense,if they are virtual. So you will always find the abstract keyword in front of the declaration of an abstract method. To tell the compiler that a method is not only virtual, but also abstract in c++, is to add `=0` after its declaration.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have inherited class A in class B, derived class B will call the function from the Base class.  You need to override the function in class B, as you want to change the Base class functionality.

You can do this with the override and virtual keywords.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/override