# Why does a base pointer can access derived member variable in virtual funtion

Tags: c++, polymorphism

```
class Base {
public:
    virtual void test() {};
    virtual int get() {return 123;}
private:
    int bob = 0;
};

class Derived: public Base{
public:
    virtual void test() { alex++; }
    virtual int get() { return alex;}
private:
    int alex = 0;
};
Base* b = new Derived();
b->test();
```

When `test` and `get` are called, the implicit `this` pointer is passed in. Is it because `Derived` classes having a sub memory layout that is identical to what a pure base object would be, then `this` pointer works for both as a base pointer and derived pointer?

Another way to put it is, the memory layout for Derived is like

```
vptr <-- this
bob
alex
```

That is why it can use `alex` in `b->test()`, right?

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking here. A lot of this doesn't make sense.

Comment: Your example is the definition of [Polymorphism](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5854581/polymorphism-in-c).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you've shown is reasonably accurate, at least for a typical implementation. It's not guaranteed to be precisely as you've shown it (e.g., the compiler might easily insert some padding between `bob` and `alex`, but either way it "knows" that `alex` is at some predefined offset from this, so it can take a pointer to `Base`, calculate the correct offset from it, and use what's there.

Not what you asked about, so I won't try to get into detail, but just a fair warning: computing such offsets can/does get a bit more complex when/if multiple inheritance gets involved. Not so much for accessing a member of the most derived class, but if you access a member of a base class, it has to basically compute an offset to the beginning of that base class, then add an offset to get to the correct offset within that base class.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Yeah, I'm not worried about multi-inheritance. AFAIK, the memory layout for multi-inheritance is compiler dependent.

Answer (score 2):

Inside of `Derived`'s methods, the implicit `this` pointer is always a `Derived*` pointer (more generically, the `this` pointer *always* matches the class type being called). That is why `Derived::test()` and `Derived::get()` can access the `Derived::alex` member.  That has nothing to do with `Base`.

The memory layout of a `Derived` object begins with the data members of `Base`, followed by optional padding, followed by the data members of `Derived`.  That allows you to use a `Derived` object wherever a `Base` object is expected.  When you pass a `Derived*` pointer to a `Base*` pointer, or a `Derived&` reference to a `Base&` reference, the compiler will adjust the pointer/reference accordingly at compile-time to point at the `Base` portion of the `Derived` object.

When you call `b->test()` at runtime, where `b` is a `Base*` pointer, the compiler knows `test()` is `virtual` and will generate code that accesses the appropriate slot in `b`'s vtable and call the method being pointed at.  But, the compiler doesn't know what derived object type `b` is actually pointing at in runtime (that is the whole magic of polymorphism), so it can't automatically adjust the implicit `this` pointer to the correct derived pointer type at compile-time.

In the case where `b` is pointing at a `Derived` object, `b`'s vtable is pointing at `Derived`'s vtable.  The compiler knows the exact offset of the start of `Derived` from the start of `Base`.  So, the slot for `test()` in `Derived`'s vtable will point to a private stub generated by the compiler to adjust the implicit `Base *this` pointer into a `Derived *this` pointer before then jumping into the actual implementation code for `Derived::test()`.

Behind the scenes, it is *roughly* (not exactly) implemented like the following pseudo-code:

```
void Derived_test_stub(Base *this)
{
    Derived *adjusted_this = reinterpret_cast<Derived*>(reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(this) + offset_from_Base_to_Derived);
    Derived::test(adjusted_this);
}

int Derived_get_stub(Base *this)
{
    Derived *adjusted_this = reinterpret_cast<Derived*>(reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(this) + offset_from_Base_to_Derived);
    return Derived::get(adjusted_this);
}

struct vtable_Base
{
    void* funcs[2] = {&Base::test, &Base::get};
};

struct vtable_Derived
{
    void* funcs[2] = {&Derived_test_stub, &Derived_get_stub};
};

Base::Base()
{
    this->vtable = &vtable_Base;
    bob = 0;
}

Derived::Derived() : Base()
{
    Base::vtable = &vtable_Derived;
    this->vtable = &vtable_Derived;
    alex = 0;
}

...

Base *b = new Derived;

//b->test(); // calls Derived::test()...
typedef void (*test_type)(Base*);
static_cast<test_type>(b->vtable[0])(b); // calls Derived_test_stub()...

//int i = b->get(); // calls Derived::get()...
typedef int (*get_type)(Base*);
int i = static_cast<get_type>(b->vtable[1])(b); // calls Derived_get_stub()...
```

The actual details are a bit more involved, but that should give you a basic idea of how polymorphism is able to dispatch virtual methods at runtime.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.
> The compiler knows the exact offset of the start of Derived from the start of Base
I thought both Derived and Base started at the same address, so the offset would always be 0, right?

Comment: @Jerry no. The offset of `Derived` is the sum of all of `Base`'s data members and padding. A `Derived` object is also a `Base` object, so it has everything that `Base` defines plus everything `Derived` defines

Comment: But when a `Base` pointer points to a `Derived` object, it basically points to the start address of `Derived` Object or the `Base` part of that `Derived` object, right?

Comment: @Jerry a `Base*` pointer points to the `Base` portion of the `Derived` object. The `Derived` portion is offset from that. Accessing `Derived` members is relative to the `Derived` portion, not the `Base` portion, so a `Derived*` pointer is needed. During virtual method dispatching, that means adjusting a `Base*` pointer into a `Derived*` pointer

Comment: That's interesting! What about in a `Derived` member function, it accesses a public `Base` member variable. Since `this` pointer is a `Derived` class pointer, if it points to the start address of `Derived` portion, how does it point back to the `Base` portion?

Comment: I think I misunderstood your reply. Just did a quick test, I printed a `Base` pointer and the `this` pointer from a virtual function inside of `Derived`, they pointed to the same address

Comment: @Jerry since the compiler knows the offset of member variables inside of `Base`, and the offset between `Base` and `Derived`, then inside a `Derived` method, the compiler can perform a simple calculation to reach `Base` member variables from a `Derived*` pointer.

Answer (score 0):

A derived class is not a seperate class but an extension. If something is allocated as derived then a pointer (which is just an address in memory) will be able to find everything from the derived class. Classes don't exist in assembly, the compiler keeps track of everything according to how it is allocated in memory and provides appropriate checking accordingly.