# what is the problem with Inheritance of this C++ code

Tags: c++

This is my code:

```
class SimpleProduct {
    char look = 'x';
    string name = "Undefined";
    string type = "Undefined";
    string description = "Undefined";
public:
    char getLook() const {return look;}
    string getType() const {return type;}
    string getName() const {return name;}
    string getDescription() const {return description;}
    SimpleProduct(char look = 'x', string &&name = "Undefined", string &&type = "Undefined", string &&description = "Undefined");
    string toString() const;
};

class TallProduct : public SimpleProduct {
public:
    TallProduct(char look, string &&name = "Undefined", string &&type = "Undefined", string &&description = "Undefined");
    string toString() const;
};


inline SimpleProduct::SimpleProduct(char look, string &&name, string &&type, string &&description) :
        look(look), name(move(name)), type(move(type)), description(move(description)) {
}

inline string SimpleProduct::toString() const {
    ostringstream ost;
    if (this->getName() == "Space") {
        ost << "";
    } else {
        ost << "Look: " << this->getLook() << ", name: " << this->getName() << ", type: " << this->getType() << ", description: "
            << this->getDescription();
    }
    return ost.str();
};

inline TallProduct::TallProduct(char look, string &&name, string &&type, string &&description){
}

inline string TallProduct::toString() const {
    return "TALL | " + SimpleProduct::toString();
}
```

And this is my test:

```
TEST(Test3, TallProduct) {
    SimpleProduct *product = new TallProduct('t', "Fresh sandwich", "sandwich", "check the expiration date");
    ASSERT_EQ("TALL | Look: t, name: Fresh sandwich, type: sandwich, description: check the expiration date",  product->toString());
}
```

The result I get is always like this:

```
"Look: x, name: Undefined, type: Undefined, description: Undefined"
```

while it should be:

```
"TALL | Look: t, name: Fresh sandwich, type: sandwich, description: check the expiration date"
```

Can you direct me where did I make a mistake? I guess the wrong part is somewhere around calling method `::tostring`, but have no idea how to call `TallProduct::toString`, instead of `SimpleProduct::toString`.

Comment: No virtual members, so no polymorphism. `product->toString()` will fire `SimpleProduct::toString`, since `SimpleProduct *product` is the decl of product.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Polymorphism in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5854581/polymorphism-in-c)

Answer (score 1):

Your `TallProduct` constructor does not initialize its base class. Write

```cpp
inline TallProduct::TallProduct(char look, string &&name, string &&type, string &&description) : 
   SimpleProduct::SimpleProduct(look, std::move(name), std::move(type), std::move(description))
{
}
```

See [delegating constructors](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list).

Futhermore, the functions of your base class are not [virtual](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/virtual). That means, a call to `product->toString()` will always call `SimpleProduct::toString` since `product` is of type `SimpleProduct *`, even though the object pointed to is of type `TallProduct`. If the functions are declared as `virtual`, the program will find out at runtime what to call.

Also you *must* declare the destructor of your base class virtual. Read about that in the above link. Otherwise you invoke undefined behavior.

Comment: Thanks, that solves half of my problem. The other half still stays on getting result `"Look: x, name:..."` instead of `"TALL | Look: t, name:"`. So basically it calls inline `string SimpleProduct::toString() const` instead of `inline string TallProduct::toString() const`.

Comment: As @WhozCraig said above, use [virtual functions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/virtual). I will edit my answer to include that.

Answer (score 1):

The other half of the problem is that: since `TallProduct` is not initializing `SimpleProduct` all class variables in `SimpleProduct` have default values.

```
char look = 'x';
string name = "Undefined";
string type = "Undefined";
string description = "Undefined";
```

As such the arguments to the `ASSERT_EQ` macro are not equal

Answer (score 1):

This is a typical case of Polymorphism. Your `*product` pointer variable is of `SimpleProduct` type but you have assigned it a `TallProduct` object and assume that calling `product->toString()` will call the `TallProduct` version of `toString()`. That is not the case.

This is called compile time / static binding. It means during compilation your compiler will bind `product->toString()` call to the `SimpleProduct` version of `toString()` because that is the logical decision right?

But if you define your `toString()` method as `virtual` in `SimpleProduct` and `TallProduct` then compiler will say, "Okay, I will not bind any method to this call right now and we'll see on runtime which method to actually call depending on the actual type of variable referenced by `*product`."

Read more about [C++ Polymorphism](https://www.w3schools.in/cplusplus-tutorial/polymorphism/).

Read more about static and dynamic binding [Virtual functions (C++ only)](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_72/rzarg/cplr139.htm)