# Base constructor calls derived constructor depending on input - Choose object sub-type at runtime

Tags: c++, oop, c++11, design-patterns, factory

Let's say I have a Human class:

```
class Human {
public:
    bool isFemale;
    double height;
    Human(bool isFemale, double height) {
        this->isFemale = isFemale;
        this->height = height;
    }
};
```

and derived classes, such as Female and Male, which implement their own methods. Do I have a way, in C++11, to determine at runtime, depending on the inputs into the Human constructor, which "sub-type" (Male or Female) Human should be? 
 I am putting different behaviour for Male and Female in their respective classes. What I am trying to do is determine at runtime whether Human is of type Female or of type Male, depending on constructor input, so I can (afterwards) apply appropriate behaviour based on its type.
The ideal would be to always call the Human constructor, and the appropriate sub-type to be chosen at runtime, depending on the parameters one enters in the constructor. If that is possible, I guess one should twist the "Human" constructor, but I'm unsure how...

Comment: You are already assigning `isFemale` at run time.

Comment: I am assigning this property to Human; now I am wondering whether the object type could be "Female" based on this property (ie dispatch object type depending on based constructor parameter). The objective afterwards is to call all appropriate methods on Human, depending on the appropriate sub-type, without necessarily using (if (isFemale...)... if(!isFemale...)). (added to post)

Comment: are you looking for a factory design pattern?

Comment: Why are you trying to do this? If you want different behaviour for Male and Female, you should put that in their respective classes.

Comment: @Kerndog73, indeed, I am putting different behavior for Male and Female in their respective classes. What I am trying to do is determine at runtime whether Human is of type Female or of type Male, depending on constructor input, so I can (afterwards) apply appropriate behavior based on its type. Sorry for the confusion...

Comment: `Human`'s constructor can only create a `Human` (even if it is the `Human` sub-object of some derived class). What you are looking for might be a factory function.

Comment: If you want to construct a female, invoke the `Female` constructor. Why do you want to create a `Human` but then turn it into a `Female` or a `Male`?

Comment: Thats not the task of the human class. You should write a separate function that decides whether the Male of Female C-str should be called.

Comment: @mfnx I did not know the expression "factory design pattern"; looking on the Wikipedia page indeed it seems appropriate to my situation!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By calling `Human`'s constructor, you can only create a `Human` object.

As far as I understand you want to create either a `Male` or `Female` object depending on the gender input that you obtain at run time. Then, you should probably consider a *factory function* for achieving this.

For example, if you define `Male` and `Female` as:

```
struct Male: public Human {
   Male(double height): Human(false, height) {}
   // ...
};

struct Female: public Human {
   Female(double height): Human(true, height) {}
   // ...
};
```

Then, you can use the following factory function, `make_human()`:

```
std::unique_ptr<Human> make_human(bool isFemale, double height) { 
   if (isFemale)
      return std::make_unique<Female>(height);
   return std::make_unique<Male>(height);
}
```

It decides at run time whether to create a `Female` or a `Male` object based on the argument passed to the `isFemale` parameter.

Just remember to make `Human`'s destructor **`virtual`** because both `Male` and `Female` classes *publicly* inherit from `Human`.

Answer (score 3):

Notice that your design allows for `Male` with `isFemale = "true"`, you can delegate this action internally avoiding erroneous flags, for sample purposes you can do something like this:  [**Live Sample**](https://onlinegdb.com/S1K0th468)

```
#include <iostream>

class Human {
private:
    int height;

protected:
    bool isFemale;

public:
    Human(){};
    Human(int height, bool isFemale = false) : height(height) {}
    virtual ~Human(){}
};

class Female : public Human {
public:
    Female(int height) : Human(height, true) {
        std::cout << "I'm a new Female, my height is " << height << std::endl;
    }
};

class Male : public Human {
public:
    Male(int height) : Human(height, false) {
        std::cout << "I'm a new Male, my height is " << height << std::endl;
    }
};
```

You can than call the appropriate constructor, for instance:

```
int main() {

    char gender;
    Human h;

    std::cout << " enter m/f: ";
    std::cin >> gender;

    switch(gender){
        case 'm':
        case 'M':
          h = Male(186);
            break;
        case 'f':
        case 'F':  
          h = Female(175);
          break;
    }
}
```

If you want to take advantage of polymorphism, take a look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5854581/6865932).

Comment: @idclev463035818 it's what the OP wants. for me I would just define it internally.

Comment: Yes, that's not a very good design, but if you notice, in the accepted answer he is confortable with that, I will change my answer to provide an alternative.