# For which class is the instance created and what is the derived class doing in this code?

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism, instantiation

What is the derived class doing in this code like:

```
class Base
{
public:
       virtual std::string Name(){ return "Base Class"}

};
class Derived : public Base
{
 public:
        std::string Name() {return "Derived Class"}
}

int main()
{
   Base* object = new Derived();
   return 0;
}
```

I was following a tutorial but didn't understand What does **Derived** class in The instantiation of **Base** Class was doing in the above code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The goal is to implement [polymorphism](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5854581/6865932), it's a OOP concept which allows you, among other things, to make derived class methods override the base class.

Consider the following:

```
class Base {
public:
    //virtual keyword allows method to be overriden
    virtual std::string Name() { return "Base Class"; }
    //virtual destructor needed for polymorphism otherwise it can lead to undefined behavior
    virtual ~Base(){} 
};

class Derived : public Base {
public:
    //optional keyword override signal the method has been overriden
    std::string Name() override { return "Derived Class"; }
};

class Derived2 : public Base {
public:
    std::string Name() override { return "Derived Class 2"; }
};

int main() {

    Base *object = new Derived();
    Base *object2 = new Derived2();
    Base *object3 = new Base();
    //collection of objects of type Base* which can hold any class of the family
    Base *collection[] = {object, object2, object3};

    for (auto &obj : collection) {//test print
        std::cout << obj->Name() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

As the comments explain, I can have a collection of different objects of the same family and when you call `Name()` the method call will deppend on the object.

Output:

```
Derived Class
Derived Class 2
Base Class
```

Answer (score 1):

modifying `main` to be :

```
int main()
{
   Base* object = new Derived();

   std::cout << object->Name() << std::endl;
   return 0;
}
```

and adding 3 missing ';' in your code, you will see that writes *Derived Class*, the called method *Name*  is the one of the real type of *object* being *Derived*.

Note while *Name* is *virtual* in *Base* it is also in *Derived* even you do not said explicitly.

`virtual` allows to use the *real* type of an object when you apply an method on, so even *object* is declared *Base* when *Name* is *virtual* the called version is the one of the real type being *Derived*

---

But if you remove `virtual` in the definition of *Name* in *Base* that writes *Base Class* because *object* being declared *Base* the called method is *Name* defined on *Base*.

The result will be the same adding `virtual` on *Derived* but still removing it on *Base*, because for the compiler *object*  being declared *Base* and *Name* being not *virtual* on *Base* that one is called without considering the real type of *object*

---

So, having :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Base
{
  public:
    virtual std::string virtualName(){ return "Base Class";}
    std::string nonVirtualName(){ return "Base Class";}
};

class Derived : public Base
{
 public:
   std::string virtualName() {return "Derived Class";} // implicitely virtual
   std::string nonVirtualName(){ return "Base Class";}
};

int main()
{
   Base* object = new Derived();

   std::cout << object->virtualName() << std::endl;
   std::cout << object->nonVirtualName() << std::endl;

   return 0;
}
```

Compilation and execution :

```
bruno@bruno-XPS-8300:/tmp$ g++ -Wall a.cc
bruno@bruno-XPS-8300:/tmp$ ./a.out
Derived Class
Base Class
bruno@bruno-XPS-8300:/tmp$
```

---

Note if you add `delete object;` at the end of `main` and because of the default destructor in not *virtual* the called destructor is the one of *Base* exactly for *nonVirtualName* and nothing is done for *Derived*. Defining the destructor *virtual* on *Base* is the right way to do, that implies the destructor is at least implicitly *virtual* on *Derived* allowing to have both destructors executed on `delete object;`