# What is this C++ OOP concept for pointers called?

Tags: c++, class, oop, pointers, inheritance

```cpp
int main() {
    doSomething(something);
}
    
string doSomething(Thing *x);
```

Here, `doSomething` is a function and `Thing` is a class. Now, I also have another inherited class called `subThing`, and I also want to `doSomething` to a pointer of `subThing`.

What do you call the concept of using pointers to `inherited classes`?  I am asking this so that I can research more on this topic.

Comment: Are you talking about "polymorphism"?

Comment: Are you asking "How does virtual function dispatch work?"

Comment: `polymorphism` is the idea that pointer's type may not exactly match the type of the thing it is pointing at.

Comment: Another keyword to check is "upcasting".

Comment: Yes, thanks! It is polymorphism.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look up [“Polymorphism”](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5854581/65863).

When `subThing` is derived from `Thing`, an instance of `subThing` is also an instance of `Thing`, so  a `subThing*` pointer can be used anywhere a `Thing*` pointer can be used.  Same thing with `subThing&` and `Thing&` references.  Just watch out for [“Object Slicing”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/). Polymorphic access to an object only works when accessing the object via a pointer or reference.